# EntityFramework Core production migrations

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

How do I update the database for production? I've moved the connection string secrets out of the application. Our CI/CD pipeline handles the token replacement within the connection string "template" that remains in the appsettings, and developers won't have production database access.

I had expected to use automatic migrations, only to discover today that Microsoft eliminated that for EF Core.

Will I have to, every time, temporarily overwrite the connection string that normally specifies my local dev copy of the database? It seems that way, but it also seems very janky process to me, so I wonder if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be a confusion of what *automatic* migration means.

Migrations consist of two parts:

1. generation from the model
2. applying to the database.

Migration generation in turn could be two types:

- automatic - at runtime, current model is compared to model produced by the last migration, and if there are changes, it generates an *automatic* migration code.
- manual - migrations are generated at design time using the design time tools (`Add-Migration` command). The auto-generated code can be modified. Modified or not, the migration is stored along with the application code.

Regardless of how migrations are generated, they *can* be applied at design time using the tools (`Update-Database` command) *and/or* at runtime.

What EF6 supports and EF Core have removed is the *auto-generation*. EF Core migrations cannot be generated at runtime - they *must* be generated at design time and stored with the application code.

Applying them at runtime is achieved with `Migrate` method called from some application startup point:

```
dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

For more info, see [Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/) and [Apply migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#apply-migrations-at-runtime) EF Core documentation topics.

Comment: Ah. I thought automatic migration referred to applying to the database. I didn't realize that it automatically *created* the migration during runtime. I was able to add `app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();` to my `Startup.Configure()` function, and all is good now. Thanks!